# If two numbers are relatively prime, is their sum relatively prime to one of them under certain conditions?

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

Let $p$ and $10^x$ be relatively prime, where $x \in \mathbb{N}$, $x > 0$ is some constant, and $p$ is prime, $p > 2$. Are $p + 10^x$ and $10^x$ relatively prime?

This isn't a homework question, but nonetheless if it's not against site etiquette it would be nice if you posted a comment before you answer, so that I can beware of spoilers. I'm stuck.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> If two numbers are relatively prime, is their sum relatively prime to
>   one of them under certain conditions?

The sum is relatively prime under *all* conditions.

Actually for your problem the only two prime factors of $10^x$ are $2,5$.  And the only two factors of $p$ is $p$ and $1$.  So do either $p,2,5$ divide $p + 10^x$?

But for a *MUCH* more general and more useful result, read on:

==========

If $W$ and $V$ have no factors (other than $1$) in common.  And if $d\ne 1$ is a factor  of $W$ then $d|W$ and $d\not \mid V$.  So $W+V = d(\frac Wd + \frac Vd)$.  $\frac Wd$ is an integer.  $\frac Vd$ is not.  So $d$ is not a factor of $W+V$.

So $W$ and $W +V$ have no non-zero factors in common.

....

Actually we can take it a step further that $\gcd(W,V) = \gcd(W, W \pm k*V) = \gcd(V, V \pm j*W)$ for any integers $j,k$.  (But don't fall into the trap that $\gcd(V, W)= \gcd (kW \pm jV, lW\pm mV)$.  That is simply false.  Utterly false.)

I'll leave the proof of that as a research project.

Comment: I feel very stupid now - thanks to everyone who answered. I gave this one the reward because it will be most helpful to the next person who finds this question.

Comment: Actually to be helpful I should have pointed out what others took as a known fact $\gcd(a,b) = \gcd(a, b+a)$

Answer (score 0):

I hope this isn't too much of a spoiler: proof by contradiction. Assume that $p+10^x$ and $10^x$ are not relatively prime, so in other words they have a common factor $d>1$. Now subtract the two numbers…

Answer (score 0):

Hint:

> $(a,a+b)=(a,b)$

So,

> $(10^x,10^x+p)=(10^x,p)=1$